# Is Martial Power 2 the only source for martial practices?

Tags: dnd-4e

The martial practices in Martial Power 2 are already pretty neat, but not quite aplenty in my opinion. New rituals are added with every other core books released. Alchemy has gotten many upgrades through MME and a handful of Dragon magazines. Has there been any extra content released for martial practices? I'm guessing MP2 came much later so there isn't, but still. The compendium doesn't give me much on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were some in Dragon 381, but all of those were also in MP2.

If you want to know what book something was printed in, or if there were things like in in other books the [Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx) can be helpful. Even if you don't have a DDI account it will still let you search and give you basic information about things, including where it was printed (though it isn't helpful if it was printed in multiple sources)

Comment: ...I did say I tried the compendium though. But yeah, my guess is that those 3 martial practices in Dragon 381 were released before MP2, then included and expanded in it; just a guess though.

Comment: @Linkyu It looks like that thought is correct, D381 was published in Nov. '09, and MP2 came out Feb. '10